# Unexpected behavior nested fields Big Query - Data Studio

Tags: nested, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have the following data in a BigQuery view:

[image]

When I want to display this data into datastudio, I got issues (probably due to the nested fields):

- data appears twice with different matches price/index date
- the index date does not show the time (HH:MM) properly but is stuck
  at 00:00

[image]

I. I would like to show one row per item, price and index_date and index_date as columns, and containing for the first the row, the first data of each field, second row the second data, etc.

```
   Subject     Price    Index_date
1. Maison      95000    2019-10-28 
2. Maison      80000    2019-12-27
```

II. I would like the index_date to be consistent with the data in BigQuery (having the same hh:mm)

Thanks!

**edit**: schema of the query result

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "6c65bb12-2441-465d-975c-81ba2b1a8d23",
    "type": "private",
    "zipcode": "69870",
    "city": "Poule-les-Echarmeaux",
    "region_name": "Rhône-Alpes",
    "department_name": "Rhône",
    "price": [
      "95000",
      "80000"
    ],
    "index_date": [
      "2019-10-28 21:46:00 UTC",
      "2019-12-27 22:12:47 UTC"
    ],
    "subject": "Maison de campagne",
    "body": "text",
    "list_id": "81711968"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please share the schema of your table? It's hard to construct the query without knowing the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I could understand, you have 2 different arrays called price and index_date.
Actually, they should be in a struct and there should be only 1 array. Here is a query that could work for your use case:

```
SELECT subject, index_date, price
FROM table,
UNNEST(price) as price_item WITH OFFSET price_offset
UNNEST(index_date) as date WITH OFFSET date_offset
WHERE price_offset = date_offset
```

An example solution with sample data is here:

```
with table as (
  select 'a' subject, [1,2] price, [3,4] date union all
  select 'b', [5,6], [7,8]
)
select subject, price_item, date_item
from table,
unnest(price) as price_item with offset price_offset,
unnest(date) as date_item with offset date_offset
where price_offset = date_offset
```

Input table:
[image]

And it's the output:
[image]

For date problem, you should fix it in DataStudio. You should click the date icon near index_date column and change it to datetime from date.